# Debian networking failure after suspend (with NordVPN)

Tags: debian, networking

I migrated to Linux a few months ago, PureOS and now on Debian 10. Generally loving it, the right decision but having a few frustrating issues with networking completely failing in a couple of situations and the only thing that fixes it is a reboot.

1. after suspend (not always repeatable)
2. after unplugging a USB  wireless adapter

**BEHAVIOUR AND WHAT I'VE TRIED**

The observed behaviour is as follows (apologies in advance for any missing info - networking is not my strong point and I'm still finding my way around, so what I have been doing may be completely wrong!)

WiFi appears to work normally and connect to a network, however can't make any outgoing requests. Oddly, `ping` fails:

`ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted`

Card is an Atheros AR9462 using `ath9k` driver (output from `lspci` follows)

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at d1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at d1080000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

NB the "access denied" still shows even when the card is working fine.

Output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:10:b3:06:0d:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 86324sec preferred_lft 86324sec
    inet6 2a02:c7f:607d:c200:de25:b539:67b5:e1e0/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2917sec preferred_lft 2917sec
    inet6 fdf3:9d9f:4b19:0:7164:9b0f:40fa:1f9c/64 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4d60:c6e4:9b2a:a0ab/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And `ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.2 metric 600
```

Forgetting the network and reconnecting doesn't resolve the issue. The machine has a hardware switch to disable the PCI wireless, toggling this also doesn't help. Renewing DHCP leases fails, as does restarting the networking services via

`sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

I've even tried removing and re-registering the wireless drivers with the kernel using `modprobe`, in combination with the above steps.

I do use a VPN service (`nordvpn` via the terminal) and after the connectivity issue occurs `nordvpn` commands fail (unresponsive at the command prompt requiring Ctrl-C). `kill`ing & restarting the `nordvpn` process does not resolve the issue.

EDIT: <strike>There are no odd rules in `iptables` that would cause a `ping` to be blocked</strike> Thanks to user A.B (see comment below) I now realise that `iptables` have been updated with a default policy to DROP, and the VPN process is most likely to be the reason. Will test further and edit the question if I can replicate / fix.

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**WHAT WORKS**

So, the only thing that does restore network connectivity is a reboot. Oddly the touchpad is sometimes completely unresponsive after a restart, so I need to restart twice.

The above is rather irritating and I've reached the end of my amateurish attempts to resolve it so I'd be super grateful for any steer! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chain OUTPUT (**policy DROP**) <--- causes `ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted`. Something fails at erasing/putting back some iptables rules. My guess would be the VPN. Does this happen when the VPN is disabled and never started?

Comment: Thanks @A.B was just writing my comment then saw you edited yours...my misinterpretaion of iptables output was a facepalm (like I said I'm kinda klutzing around!!) I'm not 100% sure but seeing as I almost always use the VPN that's the most likely culprit. I'll see if I can replicate if I never start the VPN service. Can I just manually edit the iptables if it happens again?

Comment: And I don't always shut down the VPN daemon before shutting the laptop so it's certainly a possibility.

Comment: You can alter the default policy manually yes

Comment: @A.B legend. Going to learn me some iptables and will try to replicate and see if I can recover by changing the default policy to ACCEPT. Will report back when it recurs - thanks so much!! Has been driving me nutty

Comment: If you find out what causes this, feel free to answer your question, else the partial answer will be half in those comments which is not good for stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big thanks to user A.B (see comments ) who pointed out the lack of connectivity was caused by a persistent `iptables` `DROP` policy. This seems to be a bug with the NordVPN service not resetting them to default when there is an issue when the machine suspends. Posting the solution here as advised, in case anyone else here has the same issues.

When issue occurs, `sudo iptables -L` shows:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Killing the `nordvpn` process, then resetting `iptables` rules and policies according to [this Digital Ocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-list-and-delete-iptables-firewall-rules) fixed the problem.

```
# Kill the nordvpn process
ps aux | grep nordvpn
kill -9 NORDVPND_PROCESS_NUMBER

# reset the default policies
# NB all iptables commands require root (sudo)
iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT
iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT

# flush the nat and mangle tables
iptables -t nat --flush
iptables -t mangle --flush

# flush all chains, and delete all non-default chains
iptables --flush
iptables -X
```

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem and your solution works for me, thanks! I'm going to report this bug to NordVPN ...

Comment: NordVPN says they're working on a fix, and that it should be released soon.

Comment: any update on this or link to the bug report?